# How to show the rows that have the same variable?

Tags: r

I would like to show the department that uses the same vendor using the vendor code in a very big dataset, so I guess I will need a loop for that but I am not really sure how to start.

[for example, I want to see for each vendor code, all the department that uses it, only if it's used by 3 or more department](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqdzW.png)

[see the sample of data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMPVY.png)

Comment: Please provide us with a sample dataset through `dput` and also provide your attempt at creating the desired output.

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a sample input and your expected output. This is needed to create, test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr)`: If your dataframe is named `df`, you could use `df %>% group_by(vendor_code) %>% filter(n() >= 3)`.

Comment: @Mossa Hello , i posted a sample of dataset ... and i haven't started yet , i don't know how to start

Comment: What i want to show exactly is , if a vendor code exist in 3 or more departments , i want to list them

Comment: @MartinGal what does filter(n() >= 3 mean ? and how is it linked to department

Comment: We group by `vendor_code` and then take the groups with three or more data points. That's what `filter(n() >= 3)` does.

Comment: Posting your data as images isn't a good way of sharing data. There are even people who deny that this _is_  a way of sharing data. Please take a look at the links posted on how to make a reproducible example. There you find examples how to put data into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **base R** solution.

```
# get the repeated values
dat_tb <- table(dat$vendor_code)

# select for the condition and print from the whole data set
dat[ dat$vendor_code %in% names(dat_tb[ dat_tb > 2 ]), ]

  vendor_code department
2        9966      dept2
3        9966      dept3
8        9966      dept8
9        9966      dept9
```

Data:

```
dat <- data.frame( vendor_code=rep(c(3344,9966,9966,3444,5566,3388),2),
 department=paste0("dept",1:12))
```

Comment: You don't need `rep("dept", 12)`. Just "dept" is sufficient. :-)

Comment: @Martin Gal Changed it, thanks!